# What happens when the filter size is same as that of image size in a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

In Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs), theoretically speaking, if the filter dimensions are same as that of the image (training example) dimensions, will CNNs boil down to normal Fully Connected Deep Neural Networks?

Comment: Wouldn’t maxpooling still make it different from the fully-connected network?

Comment: What if we assume that there are no pooling layers? (Just for the sake of this question).

Comment: Then I say they’re the same, except that your “CNN” is locked into having particular numbers of nodes: some integer multiple of the number of pixels. Draw out what happens with a 2x3 image and post what you find. (I’d use paint, but it doesn’t really matter.)

Comment: Sure. That would be a good exercise. Will try in my free time.

Comment: Post what you find. I want to make sure I’m right, and it will be helpful for others to see what you discover.

Comment: depends on the padding -- if no padding, then yeah seems equivalent